# ошибка has been blocked by the current security policy

Tags: linux, linux-mint

когда пытаюсь загрузиться с загрузочной флешки в windows 10, то выкидывает эту ошибку и грузиться 10-ка.

Comment: [инструкция](http://remontcompa.ru/392-kak-otklyuchit-secure-boot.html) или гуглить по ключевому слову secure boot отключить.

Comment: та да...я покопался и потом быстро нашел ответ, но теперь не могу помять язык)копаюсь, а на это найти вопрос уже довольно сложно...то есть открываю зыки, загружаю их, потом нажимаю кнопку загрузить язык(когда он уже добавился) и оно выкидывает ошибку.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это делается в BIOS (или UEFI) — как правило во вкладке «Boot». Там есть пункты «Boot mode» и «Boot priority». В каком-то из них или в обоих будет стоять что-нибудь связанное с UEFI. Нужно изменить на Normal(как вариант Legacy) — обычная загрузка.